# Can we limit both sides of an inequality involving least upper bound?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose we have the sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n \leq \sup\{a_k : k \geq n\}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\space a_n$ exists.

Can we conclude that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\space a_n \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\space \sup\{a_k : k \geq n\}$?

It seems like this is the case and I would like to use it in one of my proofs, but I can't figure out if it is true or not.

Is there a proof whether this is true or not, and if it is not true in general, what are the circumstances where it is true?

Comment: If $\lim a_n$ exists it does hardly requires a proof. But the limit need not exist.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have edited the question to clarify that the limit does exist.

Comment: What does $lub$ mean? Least upper bound? If so, the standard way of denoting it is $\sup$, because the least upper bound is more commonly known as the *supremum*

Comment: @5xum Lowest upper bound. I have edited to use the more common notation of $sup$ for supremum.

Comment: @DavidCallanan `$\sup$` and `$\lim$` make the much nicer $\sup$ and $\lim$ symbols. In future, try to use those, as $lim$ looks like $l$, multiplied by $i$, multiplied by $m$.

Comment: @DavidCallanan Also, what do you mean by "$\lim_{n\to\infty}$ exists"? Do you mean "$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$? If so, please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @5xum Thank you for the edit. Yes, that was a typo, I will edit again.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence $a_n$ converges, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\{a_k| k\geq n\}$$

which is even stronger (equality rather than inequality) than what you are asking.